# Printing Arabic content in Odoo POS Receipt

Tags: javascript, python, odoo-8, odoo-10, point-of-sale

I am trying to print arabic header and footer in Odoo POS Receipt.
but it changes arabic content which is RTL to LTR.

Other part of Receipt is in English only header footer is in arabic.
Please help me.

Comment: What have You tried so far?, Can You show us some code?

Comment: Chikhar can you show a screen photo and what you trying to do exactly

Comment: I am entering rtl arabic content in point of sale form header and footer field. Other  content is totally in english..i am using posbox printer. the pdf generated has correct content but when we are printing it arabic content is printed in reverse.